# How to pass extra custom ./configure autotools options to a Buildroot package?

Tags: autotools, configure, buildroot

E.g., I want to add the options `--enable-foo --enable-bar` to a `./configure` command.

Many `./configure` options can be set indirectly through `BR2_` configs, but many software have so many options that it would be infeasible to have one `BR2_` config for every possible `./configure` option.

Is there a general mechanism that works for all autotools packages?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no current general method as of 2017.02, since `package/pkg-autotools.mk` contains:

```
# Configure package for target
define $(2)_CONFIGURE_CMDS
    (cd $$($$(PKG)_SRCDIR) && rm -rf config.cache && \
    $$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) \
    $$(TARGET_CONFIGURE_ARGS) \
    $$($$(PKG)_CONF_ENV) \
    CONFIG_SITE=/dev/null \
    ./configure \
        --target=$$(GNU_TARGET_NAME) \
        --host=$$(GNU_TARGET_NAME) \
        --build=$$(GNU_HOST_NAME) \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --exec-prefix=/usr \
        --sysconfdir=/etc \
        --localstatedir=/var \
        --program-prefix="" \
        --disable-gtk-doc \
        --disable-gtk-doc-html \
        --disable-doc \
        --disable-docs \
        --disable-documentation \
        --with-xmlto=no \
        --with-fop=no \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --enable-ipv6 \
        $$(DISABLE_NLS) \
        $$(SHARED_STATIC_LIBS_OPTS) \
        $$(QUIET) $$($$(PKG)_CONF_OPTS) \
    )
endef
else
```

and I can't see any way to plug in arbitrary options since `$$($$(PKG)_CONF_OPTS)` is set from the `package.mk` of each package, and the other variables appear to have specific purposes as well and shouldn't be messed with.

But I think this could be easily patched if we added a:

```
$$($$(PKG)_CONF_OPTS_EXTRA)
```

and then from the CLI you could do:

```
make MYPACKAGE_CONF_OPTS_EXTRA="--enable-foo --enable-bar"
```

Finally, for some packages, you could get away with existing `make` configs, e.g. for `host-qemu`, which has not yet been converted to autotools, I manage to get my extra options simply with:

```
HOST_QEMU_OPTS="--enable-sdl --with-sdlabi=2.0"
```

because luckly that package happens to use `+=` instead of `=` on the Makefile.

Thomas' answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49570825/895245 also suggests that it is not possible without hacking up new config options.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `BR2_EXTERNAL` tree and in the `external.mk` you can override any package variable you like (well, there are a few exceptions, e.g. `<PKG>_VERSION`). You can append to the variables or override them.

Comment: Hi, but is there any variable that works for config?