# What is the proper method to modify the autotools options of a Buildroot source package using BR2_EXTERNAL?

Tags: autotools, buildroot, ntpd

I want to change the `<PKG>_CONF_OPTS` config options for a package included in Buildroot without altering the baseline `<pkg>.mk` file.  Based on what I'm reading, it shouldn't be necessary to completely override the package using the `BR2_PACKAGE_OVERRIDE_FILE` as I don't want to change the source or anything else significant.

It has been suggested that this can be done using `BR2_EXTERNAL` and `external.mk`, but I cannot find any examples and my attempts have failed.  The Buildroot documentation is quite silent on this topic, as near as I can tell, and instead only explains the creation of new packages rather than the build customization of included packages.

I have tried adding lines to `external.mk` directly as in `<PKG>_CONF_OPTS += --new-option` but this has no effect.  I have also tried creating a supplementary makefile in `package/<pkg>/<pkg>.mk` and filling in the needed information in the `Config.in` files for a "new" package but this has also failed.

I have referenced a couple of related questions that do not have complete answers given, so I am hoping to discover the general method and document it here.

[How to pass extra custom ./configure autotools options to a Buildroot package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44341188/how-to-pass-extra-custom-configure-autotools-options-to-a-buildroot-package)

[Buildroot: Build only one package as both shared and static lib, all others shared only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958904/buildroot-build-only-one-package-as-both-shared-and-static-lib-all-others-shar)

Hopefully with a couple hints we can get this figured out and then documented for others.

EDIT:  Done quite a bit of testing with this, and it's interesting to note that even the "sanity check" case of making the changes to _CONF_OPTS directly in the existing package is not having the desired effect.  In my case (trying to do a static linkage build of one particular package while leaving everything else dynamic) I find that the presence or absence of BR2_STATIC_LIBS in the _defconfig controls everything when it comes down to the final build command, despite acknowledgement to the contrary all throughout the build logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that there is no satisfactory way to accomplish this.  After going through the make process in more detail, I find that the top level defconfig `BR2_` options override the individual package options (such as, in my case, the presence or absence of `BR2_STATIC_LIBS`).

Answer (score 2):

BR2_EXTERNAL is not meant to adjust the configuration options of an existing package that is part of Buildroot itself. BR2_EXTERNAL is only meant to add new packages.

You should instead add a Config.in option to the package you're interested in, and use that to tweak its configuration.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed a new thought.  So I really don't have any choice except to modify the existing package - can you confirm that's what you are suggesting?  Also, I believe copying it into my `BR2_EXTERNAL` to replace the existing package it has its own set of problems.

Comment: One more question is I'm not really following what I would add to Config.in - wouldn't it be simply adding to the `_CONF_OPTS` inside the `<pkg>.mk` if I'm editing the existing package anyway?

Comment: I'm wondering if we need to make an improvement to Buildroot here.  In the case of `BR2_SHARED_STATIC_LIBS` perhaps we can allow the `_CONF_OPTS` in each package to dictate which to use.